# Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am receiving the below error.

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
>   row 1, column 4 (G). Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 Bulk load
>   data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the
>   specified codepage) for row 2, column 4 (G).

Input File:                                                                         `NYM,'  2016,'  Ruggiano',  CF',    8', 20',    4', 7', 0', 0', 2', 6', 2', 9', 0', 1', 0.35',  0.409', 0.65',  1.059', 0', 0', 0', 0', 2016',`

```
Team (PK, varchar 28, Not Null)  
Player (Varchar (30) Not Null)      
POS (Varchar (30) Not Null)
G (int, Not Null)          


Bulk
Insert Player_Stats
From 'C:\Users\Robert\Documents\test_Input.txt'
With
(
Fieldterminator = ',',
Rowterminator = '0x0A'
)
```

Comment: Is your "input file" information showing up correctly in this question? Because it seems to have a lot of single-quote characters in positions which make them look like delimiters, but they don't seem to be matched.

Answer (score 1):

The datatype you're trying to insert does not match the column type. It's really that simple.

Comment: In this instance I am inserting the number '4'. Type INT is incorrect? The largest number would be 3 digits. What column type should I use?

Comment: @RobertTritt Looks to me like you're inserting `        4'`. Do you not see the other characters in the file?

Comment: Here is the input file:                                                                                                There are other characters in the file.                                                   NYM,' 2016,' Ruggiano', CF', 8', 20', 4', 7', 0', 0', 2',

Comment: @RobertTritt `4'` is not an int. It is a string if you delimit by commas. Don't overcomplicate this

Comment: Thank you. It appears I need a better understanding of data types.